# Аналог оператора присваивания для shared_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointer

Возник вопрос. У меня реализован класс односвязный список List и внутренний Node. Изначально я реализовывал этот класс не используя умных указателей, но мне понадобилось их использовать. И проблема, что для shared_ptr не перегружен оператор присваивания. Например в моем классе есть поле

```
shared_ptr<Node> head;
```

и компилятор ругается на такую вот конструкцию

```
head=new Node(data);
```

Или, например, мой элемент списка (Node) содержит умный указатель типа shared_ptr на следующий элемент pNext. И вот такой код тоже не работает, ибо отсутствует перегрузка оператора =.

```
shared_ptr<Node> current=this->head;

while (current->pNext != nullptr)
{
    current = current->pNext;
}
current->pNext= new Node(data);
```

Можно ли как с обычными указателями брать и присваивать значения? Как это сделать? Надеюсь, достаточно полно описал проблему.

Comment: Вы уверены, что нужен shared_ptr а не unique_ptr?

Comment: head.reset(new Node(data));

Comment: Такое ощущение, что вы не стали читать сообщение об ошибке. А в нем было сказано не что "для shared_ptr не перегружен оператор присваивания", а что среди перегруженных операторов присваивания не удается выбрать подходящую перегрузку. И прежде чем задавать вопрос, надо было заглянуть в документацию и узнать, какие перегрузки реализует shared_ptr.

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ, то пожалуйста отметьте его как "Правильный ответ" нажав на галочку слева от ответа :)

Answer (score 1):

Строчками:

```
shared_ptr<Node> head;
head = new Node(data);
```

Вы пытаетесь присвоить умному указателю, обычный указатель. Вам нужно создать умный указатель на элемент и его уже присваивать другому умному указателю. Этого можно добиться при помощи функции `make_shared<T>`

Вот пример:

```
shared_ptr<Node> head;
head = make_shared<Node>(Node(data));
//В вашем случае можно писать
//head = make_shared<Node>(data);
```

Во втором примере аналогично. На строчке:

```
current->pNext= new Node(data);
```

Вы так же присваиваете умному указателю, обычный указатель и так же можно решить это при помощи функции `make_shared<Node>`.

```
current->pNext = make_shared<Node>(Node(data));
//Или так current->pNext = make_shared<Node>(data);
```

Так же вы можете использовать функцию `reset`

Например:

```
head.reset(new Node(data));
//или
current->pNext.reset(new Node(data));
```

Различия между `reset` и `make_shared` можете почитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836691/is-it-better-to-use-shared-ptr-reset-or-operator)